# NPM plugin "cordova-plugin-paytm" for mobile app is not working

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, paytm

Previously following set of code at config.xml working properly.

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-paytm" source="npm" spec="~0.0.8">
      <variable name="MERCHANT_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
   <variable name="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" value="Retail" />
   <variable name="WEBSITE" value="WEBSTAGING" />
</plugin>
```

But, now when I re-build/re-create the app using phonegap following error is coming:

plugin version or a dependency of this plugin is not on `npm: cordova-plugin-paytm@~0.0.8`

Comment: I had an error like this with a cordova package and had only to change the npm pachage manually

Comment: how npm can be changed? Please guide

Comment: The thing is to just downgrade or upgrade one or the other with npm, i really don't remember how i've done that